# !servericon and !uptime commands giving error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

My uptime command below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'uptime',
  aliases: ['TimeOn'], 
  description: "",
  execute(client, message, args) { 

    let totalSeconds = client.uptime / 1000;
    let days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400);
    let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    totalSeconds %= 3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
          
    let uptime = `️ ${days.toFixed()} days\n️ ${hours.toFixed()} hours\n️ ${minutes.toFixed()} minutes\n️ ${seconds.toFixed()} seconds`;
          
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Uptime ️`)
      .setThumbnail("https://imgur.com/WZMylbw.gif")
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setDescription(`**I've been online for**\n${uptime}`)

    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
};
```

When I use this command the error appears:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

---

My server icon command below:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: 'servericon',
  aliases: ['svicon'], 
  description: "",
  execute(client, message, args) {

    let img = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/${message.guild.id}/${message.guild.icon}.png?size=2048`

    let icon = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription("group icon")
      .setImage(img)

    message.channel.send(icon)
  }
};
```

When I use this command the error appears: TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Does anyone know how to resolve these errors?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `message` identifier is `undefined`, please show us how your message event correlates to your command handler. And why are you using `Discord.RichEmbed()` from `discord.js^11.x` on one and `Discord.MessageEmbed()` from `discord.js^12.x` on another?

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me on this, because you could have set it up differently, but try putting the `message` parameter first, I don't think I've really ever seen it the way you've done it, and if it's not set up that way in your command handler, it won't work like that. So `message` is probably returning `undefined` while `client` is returning the actual message. To test this, try `client.guild.id` and `client.channel.send()`.

Comment: As I've said, in `module.exports`, you export the `async function execute (client, message, args)`, which means, `execute` is a function, and the parameters will have to be the same from the module and the command handler, that's why we need to look at their command handler.